# All the nodes having an attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

Is there some kind of xpath syntax I could use to get all the nodes(including child nodes) that have an identifierref present in the xml below? I've been trying something like `XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//@identifierref");` but that doesn't return the child title node below the item nodes. Ideally I want to obtain a node list which has access to the item nodes that have identifierref present and the title nodes below them. Below is the xml I'm working with. Thanks in advance.

```
<organization xmlns:adlcp="test1" xmlns="test2">
      <title>1.2 Tester</title>
      <item identifier="C2_LESSON1">
        <title>TestName1</title>
        <item identifier="I_SCO1" identifierref="SCO01">
          <title>Tester SCO 1</title>
        </item>
      </item>
      <item identifier="C2_LESSON2">
        <title>TestName2</title>
        <item identifier="I_SCO2" identifierref="SCO01">
          <title>Tester SCO 2</title>
        </item>
      </item>
      <item identifier="C2_LESSON3">
        <title>TestName3</title>
        <item identifier="I_SCO3" identifierref="SCO01">
          <title>Tester SCO 3</title>
        </item>
      </item>
    </organization>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to obtain a node list which has
>   access to the item nodes that have
>   identifierref present and the title
>   nodes below them

```
//item[@identifier]
```

The above selects all `item` elements in the document having an `identifier` attribute.

If you want to select also the `title` element child.

```
//item[@identifier]|//item[@identifier]/title
```

But node set result order depends on host language (the most work with document order). Also there is no "grouping" feature: you can't iterate over each two because maybe some `title` is missing.

So, use first XPath expression first, and then iterate over those `item` getting the `title` with any DOM method or a relative XPath expression like:

```
title
```

Comment: Another expression without the union of two absolute path: `//*[(self::item|self::title/parent::item)[@identifier]]` but it's not shorter and might be not more efficient.